# Inconsistent thread

Tags: c#

I have the code below that produces inconsistent output.

```
string text = "t1";
new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) ).Start();

//Thread.Sleep(1);

text = "t2";
new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) ).Start();
```

Sometimes it produces t1 and t2, and sometimes it's producing double t2.
What I'm thinking right now, is that. When it's output is double t2, the first thread's captured variable value is t2 because it started after the last variable assignment. Am I right?

Note: I'm running this code on a slow machine.

Comment: This is why Resharper complains about modified "closures" sometimes. You solve it by always making a copy of the argument that you pass to a lambda if you are changing that variable after starting the lambda in a separate thread.

Comment: I've added single-threaded code demonstrating the issue mentioned by @MatthewWatson as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right; see [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) on Wikipedia.

By definition, threads do not execute synchronously, so you shouldn't expect the order of your code to unambiguously determine the behaviour of your program.

Comment: Thanks! `Race Condition` is the term I'm looking for. :)

Comment: +1 for correct term and note on ordering of calls. @FreddieFabregas, please pay attention to  Matthew Watson comment - the issue with your code is caused by closure and exposed by race condition. You can easily have similarly confusing behavior if instead of threads you simply cache lambda and call it later on the same thread.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, yeah. I'll take note of that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a simple multi threading issue.

While the 1st thread is not even started you change the value of text variable.
Then the 1st thread starts with the new value and you have a double 't2'

Answer (score 1):

'sometimes it's producing double t2'

The value of text has been changed to "t2" before the first

```
new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) ).Start();
```

has executed

If you want consistency, change to:

```
string text = "t1";
new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text) ).Start();

//Thread.Sleep(1);

string text2 = "t2";
new Thread ( () => Console.WriteLine (text2) ).Start();
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to avoid modifying value in closure (by capturing 2 different variables).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have race condition as everyone mentions.

In your case it exposes behavior of closures that most people don't expect at first: closure captures variable, not its value. The issue can be easily shown in single thread case:

```
string text = "t1";
Action a1 =  () => Console.WriteLine (text);
a1(); // prints "t1"
text = "t2";
Action a2  = () => Console.WriteLine (text) ;

a1(); // prints "t2" 
a2();
```

Answer (score -1):

Therefore the simplest way is to use a lock on the variable

This prevents one thread to access the variable while it is used by another one

Comment: -1. Adding any kind of `lock` statements will not solve anything in existing sample as the issue mainly caused by closure and exposed by threading. On other hand if you show sample that works correctly with `lock` it very well could be an answer.